# Tika child processes keep dying

Tags: jvm, apache-tika, tika-server

Tika child processes keep dying. I tried to increase the heap size to 2GB but that doesn't seem to affect anything, after ~100 files the child process just dies and the Tika server restarts it. I have 8GB RAM/4 CPUs assigned to it, and this is my `config.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <fetchers>
    <fetcher class="org.apache.tika.pipes.fetcher.fs.FileSystemFetcher">
      <params>
        <name>fsf</name>
        <basePath>/shared/input</basePath>
      </params>
    </fetcher>
  </fetchers>
  <server>
  <params>
    <forkedJvmArgs>
      <arg>-Xms2g</arg>
      <arg>-Xmx2g</arg>
    </forkedJvmArgs>
    <enableUnsecureFeatures>true</enableUnsecureFeatures>
  </params>
</server>
</properties>
```

I'm running it inside a Docker container, I ran `jstat` to see the statistics for the child process and this is what I get:

```
# jstat -gc 2132
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   110592.0 74752.0  1986560.0    5092.0   192.0   75.5   64.0   4.4        0    0.000   0      0.000    0.000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the logs for the Tika Server?